# Request downloads late delegation

Tags: skmaps

Alright,

so I have a table view, whose cells will start a offline maps download once they are tapped like so:

```
let map: SKTDownloadObjectHelper =  SKTDownloadObjectHelper.downloadObjectHelperWithSKTPackage(package) as! SKTDownloadObjectHelper
SKTDownloadManager.sharedInstance().requestDownloads([map], startAutomatically: true, withDelegate: self, withDataSource: self)
```

I define the current table view controller as the delegate for the download request. I have all the `SKTDownloadManagerDelegate`methods implemented so, updating on the progress works just fine.
However, if I go back one step in my table view hierarchy, obviously my table view controller gets thrown off the stack and thus my delegate.

So my question is simple: How can I, once I reenter the view where my download progress is shown, "re wire" my download to my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's Friday... Please forgive me.
Obviously it's in `SKTDownloadManager`. I looked in every other class definition, but this one.

```
SKTDownloadManager.sharedInstance().downloadDelegate = self
```